# How to make image responsive for all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to make my image responsive for all devices. The header has a video and an image that is placed in front of the video. When seen on the desktop the image is placed fine in the center of the container however, when resizing the window to see if responsive for smaller devices the image gets misplaced below the container.

How it looks on the desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exy2q.jpg

How it looks when resized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qnx8.jpg

My HTML code:

```
   <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header-container">

         <div class="video-container">

            <video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume= "0">

            <source src="video/backgroundAnime.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/backgroundAnime.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="video/backgroundAnime.ogv" type="video/ogg"> 

            </video>
            <div class="img-container">
             <img src="img/albayda.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.header-container{

  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.video-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-responsive{

 max-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe you can fix the issue with a CSS media query.**

When the code begins to bug at the specific pixel you can use the **following code:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

With this the browser will display your website differently on any pixel you wish. Just enter your code within the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the img tag this style :

```
object-fit:cover;
```